# could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, jpa, jackson

I try to insert some data by posting JSON, but I dont know why, it returns me an error saying that Field 'id_accessoire' could not be empty (null).

When I send my JSON with Advanced Rest Client, the field id_accessoire is not empty.

First, this i my entity (file Affaire.java) , with all the fields like they are in my database :

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "affaire")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
public class Affaire implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id", insertable = false, nullable = false)
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name = "sn", nullable = false)
  private String sn;

  @Column(name = "zc")
  private String zc;

  @Column(name = "certificat")
  private String certificat;

  @Column(name = "etat", nullable = false)
  private Boolean etat;

  @Column(name = "finEval", nullable = false)
  private Date finEval;

  @Column(name = "finRep", nullable = false)
  private Date finRep;

  @Column(name = "limiteCalendaire", nullable = false)
  private String limiteCalendaire;

  @Column(name = "date_lancement", nullable = false)
  private Date dateLancement;

  @Column(name = "accordClient", nullable = false)
  private boolean accordClient;

  @Column(name="idAccessoire", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Integer idAccessoire;

  @Column(name="idFlux", insertable = false, nullable = false, updatable = false)
  private Integer idFlux;

  @Column(name="idReparation", insertable = false, nullable = false, updatable = false)
  private Integer idReparation;

  @Column(name="idVariante", insertable = false, nullable = false, updatable = false)
  private Integer idVariante;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="idAccessoire", nullable = false)
  @JsonBackReference(value = "affaireAccess")
  private Accessoire accessoire;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="idFlux", nullable = false)
  @JsonBackReference(value = "affaireFlux")
  private Flux flux;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="idReparation", nullable = false)
  @JsonBackReference(value = "affaireRep")
  private Reparation reparation;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="idVariante", nullable = false)
  @JsonBackReference(value = "affaireVariante")
  private Variante variante;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "affaire", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  //@JsonManagedReference(value = "affecterAffaire")
  @ToString.Exclude
  private List<Affecter> affecters;

}
```

And finally, this is the JSON that I try to post, but it's not working :

```
{
  "sn":"4444AAA",
  "zc":null,
  "certificat":null,
  "etat" : false,
  "finEval": "2019-08-25",
  "finRep": "2019-09-14",
  "limiteCalendaire":"10R28",
  "dateLancement":"2019-07-19",
  "accordClient" : false,
  "idAccessoire" : 1,
  "idFlux": 1,
  "idReparation": 2,
  "idVariante" : 7,
}
```

The error is that the field "id_accessoire_ could not be empty (null)

Answer (score 0):

From you entity class, I can see that idAccessoire column in not insertable not updatable.

```
 @Column(name="idAccessoire", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Integer idAccessoire;
```

This means that irrespective of which value you set in code, it will be ignored.

Now, If idAccessoire is defined as not nullable field in your table configuration this error is thrown.

1) Do you really want this field to be not insertable or updatable? 
2) If you must specify this column as non null in database, try to specify a default value, if it suites your business logic.